# What does this operator #{var} do in ruby?

Tags: ruby, include, each

This is from a coderbyte solution to a problem that asks you to look at two integers and determine if there is any digit that occurs three times consecutively in the first number and twice consecutively in the second number. A user posted this solution (partial below), and I understand intuitively what their code is doing, but I'm not sure exactly how these #{i}'s work or what that operator is even called. Looking for more info.

It makes sense to me that you couldn't just say:
string.include?(iii) because that's just silly.

But what is the #{} doing exactly?

```
arr = num1.to_s.split("").uniq

arr.each do |i|
  if num1.to_s.include?("#{i}#{i}#{i}") && num2.to_s.include?("#{i}#{i}")
    return 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#{}` allows you to execute ruby code within a string. For example, 
    `puts "two plus two is #{2+2}.` will give out the output `"two plus two is 4."` Be careful though, `#{}` will only work between double quotes and will not work between single quotes. In your example the `#{i}` will evaluate to the var `i` from `arr.each do |i|`

Answer (score 0):

It's the string interpolation syntax: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation